# Keeping Scanner Input at the bottom of the console

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I am currently written a small CLI for a school project which intends to introduce Socket Programming and Multi-Threaded Programming. We are basically implementing a type of file transfer protocol. I am currently having a few issues with formatting the CLI. Being of the multi-threaded nature of the program, there are times where an input is being requested and then an output is displayed. This makes the overall interaction between the user and the CLI awkward as now the uses has to enter in an input after an output has occured.

I was wonder if there is a way, with standard Java I/O, to keep the input always at the bottom of the CLI even when new messages are coming in.

For example, the output currently looks something like this:

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5001
mytftp> pwd
/Users/Shawn/Desktop/Computer Science/CSCI4780 Distributed Systems/Project2/server
mytftp> pwd &
mytftp> 
/Users/Shawn/Desktop/Computer Science/CSCI4780 Distributed Systems/Project2/server
ls
.DS_Store
sdf
clientFile.txt
mytftp>
```

But I am expecting something like this:

```
Connected to 127.0.0.1:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5001
mytftp> pwd
/Users/Shawn/Desktop/Computer Science/CSCI4780 Distributed Systems/Project2/server
mytftp> pwd &
/Users/Shawn/Desktop/Computer Science/CSCI4780 Distributed Systems/Project2/server
mytftp> ls
.DS_Store
sdf
clientFile.txt
mytftp>
```

Note: The "&" here means "run this command on a seperate thread". This is why, during the next execution, the "mytftp>" prompt shows up first and then the results of the thread are displayed. I would just like the current prompt to stay at the bottom at all times. Side note, the & on the pwd command is not added for increased performance. It would typically only be used for the file upload and download commands but it is used here as an example.

I am not sure if this is possible but alternatives would be appreciated.

**Just to reiterate, the flow would like**:

`Connection Established:` Connected to 127.0.0.1:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5001
`Command is entered into new thread`: mytftp> pwd &
`Next prompt is shown ready for a new command`: mytftp>

Once the results for `pwd &` comes in, I would like the prompt to come down:

`Connection Established:` Connected to 127.0.0.1:5000 and 127.0.0.1:5001
`Command is entered into new thread`: mytftp> pwd &
`Space was made for the prompt and results shown`: /Users/Shawn/Desktop/Computer Science/CSCI4780 Distributed Systems/Project2/server
`Next prompt is shown ready for a new command`: mytftp>

Answer (score 0):

The solution I ended up coming up with was using the `\r` character and rearranging the flow of prompt. Rather than:

```
while true:
    show prompt
    get input
    do some socket programming here
```

I choose to go with the following schema

```
show prompt
while true:
    get input
    do some socket programming here and each socket response (system.out) should start with \r, followed by the message, followed by "\nmytftp>".
```

This meant that every message that would come from the server would remove the current prompt but using the return-carriage and then add the prompt back before it.